# apparmor: how to allow emacs snap to redirect output to files on CLI?

Tags: snap, emacs, apparmor

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and:

```
$ which emacs
/snap/bin//emacs
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 27.1
```

If I set up this file:

**mwe.el**

```
(defun output ()
  (princ
   (apply #'concat (nthcdr 5 command-line-args))))
```

and run

`emacs --batch -l ~/bin/mwe.el --eval "(output)" bla bla bla`

I see: `blablabla` printed out.

However, if I try to redirect output to a file I get this:

```
$ emacs --batch -l ~/bin/mwe.el --eval "(output)" bla bla bla > foo.txt
/snap/emacs/857/usr/bin/emacs: Write error to standard output: Permission denied
```

Syslog says:

> Sep  5 21:01:20 Proteus kernel: [35741.583507] audit: type=1400 audit(1599336080.881:188): apparmor="DENIED" operation="file_inherit" profile="/snap/core/9804/usr/lib/snapd/snap-confine" name="/home/joe/bin/foo.txt" pid=62355 comm="snap-confine" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=1000 ouid=1000

How to fix this?